# Form reload/refresh

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working on a project where I need the form to run code when the form reloads.

I have variables that get changed in a tempVar but I want the running form to run the a command after the form reloads/refresh itself. Is there a way I can do this?

The script I'm running is simple and I have tested it to check that its not the script itself that is causing the problem.

I have tried things like On Load and On Render, but I think I have lost the plot now, so I am looking for new ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific [order of events for loading forms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx). The following code should give you the result you are after:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' Insert Code Here
End Sub
```

Comment: edit your form, select 'property sheet' from the design ribbon, select the 'events' tab, on the 'On Load' event click the '...' button, select 'code builder'

Comment: ok i get it.

i have used the macro builder to design the script can you help turn it over to VBA. its been ages since i have used VB,

Condition: IsNull([TempVars]![tmpDateFrom]) And IsNull([TempVars]![tmpDateTo])
Action: SetProperty
Argument: cmd_button_1, Enabled, 0
Condition: Not IsNull([TempVars]![tmpDateFrom]) And Not IsNull([TempVars]![tmpDateTo])
Action: SetProperty
Argument: cmd_button_1, Enabled, -1

Comment: @MasterT There is a menu option within access to `Convert Macro's to Visual Basic` try that first as it should do what you need.

Comment: I have looked but i can not find it.

Comment: @MasterT Open your macro and you should see `Convert Macros to Visual Basic` on the ribbon.